# Can var be used as a global variable that can be accessed by any method in the form in Visual

Tags: c#, winforms

Final leg of the project, realized that some of the variables had to be declared in the form1 class for it to be accessible to other parts of the program; however one important variable that is used for calculation keeps returning the following error :`Error  1   The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration`. If I change its data type to int however I'm told that `int` does not contain a definition for SUM which I use to help calculate payment. I'm using MVS 2010
CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Items> STOCK = new List<Items>();
        int selecteditems = new List<Items>();
        decimal subt;
        decimal GCT = 16.50m;
        decimal GCTamt;
        decimal total;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            this.STOCK = new List<Items>
           {
            new Items{ id = 1, Name = "Bun", Price = 100},
            new Items{ id = 2, Name = "Soda", Price = 80},
            new Items{ id = 3, Name = "Cheese", Price =70},
            new Items{ id = 4, Name = "Tissue", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 5, Name = "Fabuloso", Price = 140},
            new Items{ id = 6, Name = "Grace Mackerel", Price = 90},
            new Items{ id = 7, Name = "Rice", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 8, Name = "Flour", Price = 40},
            new Items{ id = 9, Name = "Sugar", Price = 30},
           };





        }



        public class Items
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }

        private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            STOCK.ForEach(x => strBuilder.Append(string.Format("ID {0} - Name: {1} Price: {2:C2}", x.id, x.Name, x.Price)));
            menu.Text = menu.Text + strBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button B = (Button)sender;
            Disp.Text = Disp.Text + B.Text;
        }


        private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var STOCKDict = STOCK.ToDictionary(x => x.id);

            int id;

             do
             {
                 if (Disp.Text ==  "x")
            if (!int.TryParse(Disp.Text, out id))
            {
                Disp2.Text = ("Enter number or 'x' ");
            }
            else
            {
                if (STOCKDict.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    var item = STOCKDict[id];
                    selecteditems.Add(item);
                    Disp2.Text = Disp2.Text + (item.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    Disp2.Text = (id + " is not available");
                }

                Disp.Text = " ";
            } 
            } while (true);
        }



        public void subtot_TextChanged( object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           subt = selecteditems.Sum(i=>i.Price);
            GCT = 16.50m;
            GCTamt = (subt*GCT/100);
            total = subt+GCTamt;
            subtot.Text = subtot.Text + subt;
        }

        public void TaxDisp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           TaxDisp.Text = TaxDisp.Text+GCTamt; 
        }


        }






    }
```

Comment: The line `int selecteditems = new List<Items>();` (which I assume is what you're talking about) is contradicting itself. You're creating a variable with the type `int`, and trying to assign it a value of type `List<Items>`. Change `int` to `List<Items>`. And to answer the question in the title, no `var` cannot be used in global variables, as global variable types are  assigned at compile time and `var` can only be used at runtime.

Comment: @Jesse Instance Fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Items> selecteditems = new List<Items>();
```

`selectedItems` will contain a `List<Items>` and needs to be declared as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `selecteditems`, you don't want it to be an `int`. You assign to it `new List<Items>()`, so the type should be `List<Items>`:

```cs
List<Items> selecteditems = new List<Items>();
```